# Issue with an example in "How to transfer data to an Excel workbook "

Tags: c#, excel

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023 it's the first example: "Use Automation to Transfer Data Cell by Cell" Below are the variables I declared for the example.

```
Excel.Application m_objExcel;
Excel.Workbooks m_objBooks;
Excel._Workbook m_objBook;
Excel.Sheets m_objSheets;
Excel._Worksheet m_objSheet;
Excel.Range m_objRange;
string m_strSampleFolder = @"C:\VBtest\PRACTICEProgramming\INDIVIDUALprograms\EXCEL";
string m_objOpt = @"C:\VBtest\PRACTICEProgramming\INDIVIDUALprograms\EXCEL";
Excel.Font m_objFont;
```

Basically everything runs fine. The issue is when the app is running, I get an error message.

"COMException was unhandled

Excel cannot access 'EXCEL'.  The document may be read-only or encrypted."

I'm thinking the value I declared for m_objOpt is declared wrong or it doesn't like the value. I tried creating a premade .XLS file but that doesn't work. I also tried putting a name for the xls but the add method wants to find the xls in the default path which I don't want.

I don't know what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the file extension at the end of m_objOpt... You can try to add .xls or .xlsx to it, or something else regarding the file extension.

Comment: Yeah I tried naming the file test.xls but I have to have the file already premade and when it is premade it gives the same error message again. Even if I don't put an xls extension, it does it automatically.

Comment: Well to be exact, if I already premade the file, I get an error message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC